# retrieving all details irrespective of conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a query that will be retrieving the members who have the pay method type is cash and memberstatustype have id's 2 , 3 , 6 . The query working fine when the members have pay method type is cash and dd and card  but it will retrieve the all details of members who dont have paymethod is card   and this is my query

```
SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode,members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob,30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod/DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, memberToMship_StartDate) As monthly_amount, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate,IF(mshipOption_Period='year', TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),  TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate ) ) *memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id 
WHERE 
    membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card' OR  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2' OR  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = '3'  OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6';
```

can any one pls help me on this .... 
am i doing any thing wrong in   "OR condition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause needs to look like this:

```
WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card' 
AND (mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2' 
OR  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = '3'  
OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6');
```

Your original query looks for people who have either one of those:

- membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card'
- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2'
- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='3'
- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6'

What you wanted was people who have

- membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card'

AND one of the following:

- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2'
- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='3'
- mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6'

Comment: is it posssible to get the members who hav paymentmethod is card and mshipstatustype id hav any of following mshipstatustypes

Comment: thats what my query does, but you can also put them in a list and use `IN` like Parkyprg

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode,members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob,30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod/DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, memberToMship_StartDate) As monthly_amount, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate,IF(mshipOption_Period='year', TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),  TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate ) ) *memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id 
LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id 
WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card' 
  AND  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id in ('2', '3', '6');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that where clasuse this run faster

```
WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card' 
AND mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id in('2','3','6')
```